# Baffled, where are files?

Tags: asp.net, .net

I have to learn how an existing website works from scratch (no documentation). So I downloaded the files from the web server onto my local machine. In the default.master, there are links to aspx pages:

```
<div class="mainNav">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="Begin.aspx" id="mfa5"><img alt="Begin Your Order" hover="images/a-main-nav-start.gif" src="images/a-main-nav-start.gif"></a></li>
        <li><a href="Inspiration.aspx" id="mfa6"><img alt="Inspiration Center" hover="images/a-main-nav-inspiration.gif" src="images/a-main-nav-inspiration.gif"></a></li>                        
    </ul>
</div>
```

The part that baffles me is that I cannot find any of these files (begin.apsx, inspiration.aspx) in the same directory, let alone the entire project.

But on the live website, the links work perfectly. Where in the world are these files? I have no idea what's going on here?

Comment: Did you include _all_ files onto your machine? Why don't you create a folder on your Desktop and label it something like Website, then copy and paste all the folders and files into Website and see if that works. It sounds like you don't have all the files on your local machine. Or create a blank `begin.aspx` and `inspiration.aspx` in the same folder you have that code on your local machine.

Comment: Note that if you copied the website, you probably got the compiled dlls, not the soure .cs or .vb files. You need the original solution/project for that.

Comment: Hans. On the web server, I do not find/see these files. Even a website is compiled on the local machine and the minimum files necessary are placed onto the web server, meaning you exclude the .cs files, you still need the .aspx files on the web server, right? - If this is correct, why do I not see these files on the web server? I see lots of other .aspx files, but not the ones that I listed in OP.

Comment: Does it use some sort of URL rewriting? Maybe check the Web.Config and see if there is anything obvious

Comment: @nanonerd - You are right, you would still (usually - see answers) need the .aspx files on the server. My remark about .cs/.vb files was in addition to that: you wouldn't be able to make much sense of the way the site works without those.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect that the website is either using a CMS of some sort, which means that the pages would not exist as physical files, but rather reside within a database.

OR

The website is using some URL re-writing and that they all might be routed to another page.

Can you not ask the person who wrote the website? or someone who manages the website?

Comment: "Can you not ask the person who wrote the website? or someone who manages the website?" - I wish it was that easy. Original vendor is on bad terms with company. There is no documentation. My first day on the job and I am stumped/stuptified on this ...

Comment: THere is a <rewrite> section in the web.config ... but nothing in there seems to connect/work with the missing files in OP ...

Comment: @nanonerd Check in the web.config for database connection strings. If they exist, then look in the database for anything relating to these pages.

Comment: Ok, it's a month later and I figured I should post a follow up as I now see what's happening. Tim, you had the best answer (given the limited info). It is set up using a custom CMS (akin to Wordpress). So the website uses a lot of templates and URL rewrites and the page data is pulled from a database. It became more clear as I saw the backend and found the database table with the URL mappings. I don't know exactly where the code is that handles the rewrites, but overall, at least I understand what's going on. Thank you and also to everyone who tried to assist ... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

The website might be precompiled. So, you wont be able to find any pages such as somefile.aspx.cs or somefile.aspx. All the code is precompiled to assemblies and if published with mark up protection even the .aspx files will be precompiled.

Comment: Is this correct? It's just the .cs files that get put into DLLs, right? Not the .aspx files ... besides, I see a bunch of .aspx files in the root directory, just not the ones in the OP ... stumped, I am ...